# Integrating VoiceFlow Bot into FlutterFlow - Returning NULL Value

Tags: json, chatbot, flutterflow

I am trying to integrate my VoiceFlow Bot into FlutterFlow. In FlutterFlow backend the API call is working properly.

On the front end, when I initiate the chat and enter a query, the bot returns with "NULL".

I believe I have the following issues:

1. Improper Launch request to initiate the chat upon page load
2. Possible error in JSON custom code return

- `return json.decode('{"payLoad": "userID", "content": "$prompt"}');`

3. Possible error in JSON paths

- `$[:].payload.message`
- `$[:].payload.slate.id`
- `$[:].type`

Any help would be much appreciated!

I have tried the above code to rectify.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.